# Add latest commit info on login footer using login_footer hook

Tags: git

I am using `login_footer` hook to display some info below the login form.

I need to display there info from the last commit of my plugin.

**Hook definition:**

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'login_footer', $plugin_admin, 'e4afz_login_footer' );
```

**Function:**

```
public function e4afz_login_footer() {
    global $E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR;
    ?>
    <style>
        #e4afz-login-footer-container {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="e4afz-login-footer-container">
        <p>&copy <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?> , Platform Version: <?php echo $this->version; ?></p>
        <p><?php
            echo shell_exec( "git log --git-dir ='" . $E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR . ".git" . 
                             "' -1 --pretty=format:'%h - %s (%ci)' --abbrev-commit --work-tree ='" . $E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR );
            ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

The **global variable** is defined as follows on the main plugin file:

```
$E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
```

I am getting `NULL` result from the shell_exec.

Ideas?

**ADDITIONAL TRIES:**

Also tried to get what i need form my main plugin file:

```
$E4AFZ_LAST_COMMIT     = shell_exec( "git log -1 --git-dir=" . ABSPATH . "/wp-content/plugins/e4afz-wp/.git" . " --work-tree=" . ABSPATH . "/wp-content/plugins/e4afz-wp/ 2>&1" );
```

I am getting a `"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"` as a result

Comment: Is PHP running in safe mode on your server? If so, `shell_exec()` is disabled, [per the notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: I think no because i am getting a "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: When I run that `git` command, I have to put the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` flags *before* the `log -1[…]` part. (Probably just an antiquated version.) Are you able to run the same command on the command line and get something valid?

Comment: What about using git (post-*) hooks instead, e.g. to generate some custom info to a file that WP can read? Maybe even possible to use a script that uses e.g. wp-cli to write that info to the WP database.

Comment: @PatJ You should really make your comment an answer to accept it. It sems that putting log -1 at the end, does the job!!!

Comment: Done. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: This isn't really a Wordpress question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, I tried to run `git log --git-dir='[dir].git' -1 --work-tree='[dir]'` and it gave me an error. When I ran `git --git-dir='[dir].git' --work-tree='[dir]' log -1`, it worked as expected.

So your code should probably be

```
 echo shell_exec( 
   "git --git-dir ='$E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR.git' 
    --pretty=format:'%h - %s (%ci)' --abbrev-commit 
    --work-tree ='$E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR'
    log -1 
);
```

Also: PHP expands variables inside double quotes, so because your string is wrapped in `"`, you don't need to break the `$E4AFZ_PLUGIN_ROOT_DIR` variable out of the quotes. IMHO, this makes the code easier to read.

### References

- [`git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) -- has the `git-dir`, `--work-tree`, etc. flags
- [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)